# How to add item weight to new email order in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, templates, woocommerce

I am currently customizing shop for the customer and I am stuck on how to add a weight field to email which arrives to customer after he finishes the order.

I was able to add this filed to product detail and cart and checkout page but I am not able to put this information to email settings. I added last item Weight.

I was only able to this in `emaiů-order-detail.php`

```html
<tr>
    <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </th>
    <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </th>
    <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </th>
    <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <?php $weight_unit = get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit'); ?>
        <?php echo $product->get_weight()*$qty.weight_unit; ?>
    </td>
```

You need to add the above code in /woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php around line 84 for adding the data into the mail.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me. You saved me a headache. Just one more thing - is there a way to add weight symbol (kg)?

Comment: What about dedicated `wc_format_weight()` function, much more efficient and compact, that you can use like: `<?php echo wc_format_weight( $product->get_weight() ); ?>`

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much.

Is there also a way to remove variant field under product name in email?